# Is there a limit to the number of Machine Owner Keys I can enroll?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, multi-boot, uefi

I installed nvidia driver in ubuntu. It asked to enroll a MOK(Machine Owner Key). I did it. Now I want to remove ubuntu from my PC. I don't need that machine owner key anymore. I need advice on the following -

- How do I remove that?
- Do I need to remove it if I delete the Ubuntu partition from the hard disk?
- Will there be a problem if I let that Machine Owner Key exist? Is there a limit to the number of MOKs we can enroll? If I again want to install some linux distro later, will there be any problems?

I dual-booted ubuntu with windows 10.

Any advice/idea/suggestion will help very much because I need to delete the partition now itself. I think I can just delete the partition and later if I install linux and graphics driver, again I can put another MOK. What is your opinion on this?

Edit: Even if you don't have an answer, I want to know what you think about it. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a firm answer, but it's clear that multiple MOKs are possible
in a computer.

MOKs are a part of
[Secure Boot](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#initial_shim)
used to sign an EFI binary.
They are managed by
[mokutil](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mokutil.1.html)
to list, export, add and delete MOKs.

The
[Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#MOK_-_Machine_Owner_Key)
says:

> Keys can be added and removed in the MOK list by the user, entirely separate from the distro CA key. The mokutil utility can be used to help manage the keys here from Linux userland, but changes to the MOK keys may only be confirmed directly from the console at boot time.

Installing any third-party software with Secure Boot requires registering new MOK
into the EFI. Any Linux installer registers a new MOK variable before it finishes
the installation, so you are not likely to encounter a problem later on.

For cleaning up on MOKs, see also the post
[Is it possible to delete an enrolled key using mokutil without the original .der file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805152/is-it-possible-to-delete-an-enrolled-key-using-mokutil-without-the-original-der)

Answer (score 0):

MOK are stored in nvram. In addition, the nvram is shared with other data. So, the answer is "it depends".

For information, in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401737/couldnt-create-moklist-volume-full-grub-doesnt-start-at-all), the user seems to have troubles after to have enrolled 77 keys (in fact, he has 77 "Forbidden signatures", but I guess they use the same storage space).